# How many ways can you pick $7$ non-consecutive integers from $1$ to $n$? Where $n$ is any positive integer. Express your answer in terms of $n$.

Tags: combinatorics

I just want to get a general idea on figuring out how many ways I can choose $7$ non-consecutive numbers in a certain number range.

Comment: Easier, I expect, to compute the number of ways to choose $7$ consecutive numbers in the region, then subtract that from the total number of ways to choose $7$.

Comment: Should the numbers be pairwise non-consecutive, or 'not all consecutive'? The question suggests the former to me, but lulu for one seems to intepret it as the latter.

Comment: And where did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts on it? What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: They are all non-consecutive. Example:1,3,5,7,9,11,13

Comment: This is the result of a equation I was solving.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(n,m)$ be the number of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of cardinality $m$ such that no two members of the subset are consecutive.
Conditioning on whether $n$ is in the subset, you get the recursion
$$ F(n,m) = F(n-2,m-1) + F(n-1,m)$$
with boundary conditions $F(n,0) = 1$, $F(0,m) = 0$ for $m \ge 1$, $F(1,1) = 1$, $F(1,m) = 0$ for $m \ge 2$.

EDIT: The solution is
$$ F(n,m) = \cases{{n-m+1 \choose m} & if $n \ge 2m-1$\cr 0 & otherwise}
$$

Answer (score 3):

We want to count the number of ways to select integers $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots , x_7$ subject to $1 \le x_1$, $x_1 < x_2-1$, $x_2 < x_3-1$, $x_3 < x_4-1$, ... , $x_6 < x_7-1$, $x_7 \le n$.  An equivalent set of inequalities is
$$1 \le x_1 < x_2-1 < x_3-2 < x_4-3 < x_5-4 < x_6-5 < x_7-6 \le n-6$$
So the number of acceptable ways to select $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots x_7$ is the same as the number of ways to select $x_1, x_2-1, x_3-2, \dots x_7-6$ in the range $1$ to $n-6$, which is simply
$$\binom{n-6}{7}$$

Answer (score 2):

So let $n(7,r)$ be the number of ways of picking $7$ non-consecutive integers between $1$ and $r$.

Now examine $n(7,r+1)$ - either the seven integers are from the first $r$ giving $n(7,r)$ or $r+1$ is one of the integers, and the remaining $6$ are from the first $r-1$, giving $n(6,r-1)$ possibilities (with obvious notation).

So you get a number of recurrences to solve of the general form $n(k,r+1)=n(k,r)+n(k-1, r-1)$

You can use these together with initial values for simple cases.

Comment: Note the indices are reversed from Robert Israel's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Let us initially take $n=16$ for illustrating.
Apart from the $7$ numbers that are to be non-consecutive, there are $(16-7) = 9$ other numbers.

The $7$ chosen numbers could be any $7$ at the $(9+1)$ uparrows, as depicted below.

$\uparrow\boxed. \uparrow\boxed . \uparrow\boxed . \uparrow \boxed . \uparrow \boxed. \uparrow \boxed. \uparrow\boxed . \uparrow\boxed . \uparrow\boxed . \uparrow $

Thus the # of ways $=\dbinom{16-7+1}{7}$,

For picking $m$ non-consecutive numbers in a string of $n$ consecutive numbers,

this easily generalises to $\dbinom{n-m+1}{m},\;\; n\ge2m-1$